# Armor and weapon enhancments

Tags: dnd-5e, gm-techniques

I'm a new DM and I'm starting a new 5th edition campaign which will be a modification of the starter set i.e. set in Faerun on the Sword Coast.  I wanted to start my group out with the choice of a +1 bonus to either a weapon (could substitute MW) or a magic bonus to a piece of armor given to them as incentive by their benefactor.

What would be the best mechanism to achieve this for a 1st level party knowing they have not much money or time? In a large town like Neverwinter, are there magic users that can enchant armor in less than or equal to a day?

Comment: So you're looking for an in fiction explanation for *why/how* they've acquired this item?

Comment: Presumably a benefactor rich enough to sponsor an adventuring group has MW and or +1 items pretty much on command, or can send someone shopping in the district for it. No real game mechanics necessary.

Comment: Yes to wax eagle and thanks to JohnP.  I was thinking the Dwarf benefactor could tell the party that's he's called in some favors from an enchantress etc. to imbue an item of their choice or offer a masterwork weapon.

Comment: In general there is not a magic economy in 5e by default. Common magic items can be purchased in limited availability. Magic items are meant to be rarer and not a requirement for PCs to be powerful in combat. Its totally fine if you wanna go that route though, just wanted to give you some wider system background.

Comment: Thanks Joshua...then perhaps an amulate or ring of some type that would would give a one daily advantage roll (luck) would be more in keeping?

Comment: What you're asking is largely a matter of opinion and taste. It's *your* world, do whatever you like, go nuts. (And as it's a matter of opinion/taste, it's off-topic and I must vote to close.)